# How do I calculate points remaining for next level?

Tags: php, function

I'm developing a leveling system and have been able to get it to calculate levels like I want, however I want to show the user how much experience is needed until next level and simply can't figure it out.

```
function experience($L) {
    $a=0;
    for($x=1; $x<$L; $x++) {
        $a += floor($x+300*pow(2, ($x/7)));
    }
    return floor($a/4);
}
function level($experience) {
    $returned = 0;
    $level = 0;
    while ($returned <= $experience) {
        $level++;
        $returned = experience($level);
    }
    return $level - 1;
}
```

Based on this xp table we started with (keeps going until 99)

```html
if ($reupxp >= 7842) { $reuplevel = 25; }
if ($reupxp >= 7028) { $reuplevel = 24; }
if ($reupxp >= 6291) { $reuplevel = 23; }
if ($reupxp >= 5624) { $reuplevel = 22; }
if ($reupxp >= 5018) { $reuplevel = 21; }
if ($reupxp >= 4470) { $reuplevel = 20; }
if ($reupxp >= 3973) { $reuplevel = 19; }
if ($reupxp >= 3523) { $reuplevel = 18; }
if ($reupxp >= 3115) { $reuplevel = 17; }
if ($reupxp >= 2746) { $reuplevel = 16; }
if ($reupxp >= 2411) { $reuplevel = 15; }
if ($reupxp >= 2107) { $reuplevel = 14; }
if ($reupxp >= 1833) { $reuplevel = 13; }
if ($reupxp >= 1584) { $reuplevel = 12; }
if ($reupxp >= 1358) { $reuplevel = 11; }
if ($reupxp >= 1154) { $reuplevel = 10; }
if ($reupxp >= 969) { $reuplevel = 9; }
if ($reupxp >= 801) { $reuplevel = 8; }
if ($reupxp >= 650) { $reuplevel = 7; }
if ($reupxp >= 512) { $reuplevel = 6; }
if ($reupxp >= 388) { $reuplevel = 5; }
if ($reupxp >= 276) { $reuplevel = 4; }
if ($reupxp >= 174) { $reuplevel = 3; }
if ($reupxp >= 83) { $reuplevel = 2; }
if ($reupxp >= 1) { $reuplevel = 1; }
```

Comment: Just added a more basic version of the code.

Comment: Can you update your question to more specifically point out the problem you are trying to solve? I personally have no idea what you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your methods are working fine, and maybe you might just need a multidimensional array to structure you inputs.

```
$arr = [
    '0' => [
        'experience' => 7842,
        'level' => 25],
    '1' => [
        'experience' => 7028,
        'level' => 24],
    '2' => [
        'experience' => 6291,
        'level' => 23],
    '3' => [
        'experience' => 5624,
        'level' => 22],
    '4' => [
        'experience' => 5018,
        'level' => 21],
    '5' => [
        'experience' => 4470,
        'level' => 20],
    '6' => [
        'experience' => 3973,
        'level' => 19],
    '7' => [
        'experience' => 3523,
        'level' => 18],
    '8' => [
        'experience' => 3115,
        'level' => 17],
    '9' => [
        'experience' => 2746,
        'level' => 16],
    '10' => [
        'experience' => 2411,
        'level' => 15],
    '11' => [
        'experience' => 2107,
        'level' => 14],
    '12' => [
        'experience' => 1833,
        'level' => 13],
    '13' => [
        'experience' => 1584,
        'level' => 12],
    '14' => [
        'experience' => 1358,
        'level' => 11],
    '15' => [
        'experience' => 1154,
        'level' => 10],
    '16' => [
        'experience' => 969,
        'level' => 9],
    '17' => [
        'experience' => 801,
        'level' => 8],
    '18' => [
        'experience' => 650,
        'level' => 7],
    '19' => [
        'experience' => 512,
        'level' => 6],
    '20' => [
        'experience' => 388,
        'level' => 5],
    '21' => [
        'experience' => 276,
        'level' => 4],
    '22' => [
        'experience' => 174,
        'level' => 3],
    '23' => [
        'experience' => 83,
        'level' => 2],
    '24' => [
        'experience' => 1,
        'level' => 1],
];

function experience($L)
{
    $a = 0;
    for ($x = 1; $x < $L; $x++) {
        $a += floor($x + 300 * pow(2, ($x / 7)));
    }
    return floor($a / 4);
}
function level($experience)
{
    $returned = 0;
    $level = 0;
    while ($returned <= $experience) {
        $level++;
        $returned = experience($level);
    }
    return $level - 1;
}

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    var_dump(level($value["experience"]));
    var_dump(experience($value["level"]));
}
```

#### Ouput

```
int(25)
float(7842)
int(24)
float(7028)
int(23)
float(6291)
int(22)
float(5624)
int(21)
float(5018)
int(20)
float(4470)
int(19)
float(3973)
int(18)
float(3523)
int(17)
float(3115)
int(16)
float(2746)
int(15)
float(2411)
int(14)
float(2107)
int(13)
float(1833)
int(12)
float(1584)
int(11)
float(1358)
int(10)
float(1154)
int(9)
float(969)
int(8)
float(801)
int(7)
float(650)
int(6)
float(512)
int(5)
float(388)
int(4)
float(276)
int(3)
float(174)
int(2)
float(83)
int(1)
float(0)
```

Calculation to the next level might be simple. You might just take the difference between current experience value and the next experience one, maybe divide it to all points (e.g., 10,000), maybe calculate a percentage.

You can modify the equation however you wish:

```
$arr = [
    '0' => [
        'experience' => 7842,
        'level' => 25],
    '1' => [
        'experience' => 7028,
        'level' => 24],
    '2' => [
        'experience' => 6291,
        'level' => 23],
    '3' => [
        'experience' => 5624,
        'level' => 22],
    '4' => [
        'experience' => 5018,
        'level' => 21],
    '5' => [
        'experience' => 4470,
        'level' => 20],
    '6' => [
        'experience' => 3973,
        'level' => 19],
    '7' => [
        'experience' => 3523,
        'level' => 18],
    '8' => [
        'experience' => 3115,
        'level' => 17],
    '9' => [
        'experience' => 2746,
        'level' => 16],
    '10' => [
        'experience' => 2411,
        'level' => 15],
    '11' => [
        'experience' => 2107,
        'level' => 14],
    '12' => [
        'experience' => 1833,
        'level' => 13],
    '13' => [
        'experience' => 1584,
        'level' => 12],
    '14' => [
        'experience' => 1358,
        'level' => 11],
    '15' => [
        'experience' => 1154,
        'level' => 10],
    '16' => [
        'experience' => 969,
        'level' => 9],
    '17' => [
        'experience' => 801,
        'level' => 8],
    '18' => [
        'experience' => 650,
        'level' => 7],
    '19' => [
        'experience' => 512,
        'level' => 6],
    '20' => [
        'experience' => 388,
        'level' => 5],
    '21' => [
        'experience' => 276,
        'level' => 4],
    '22' => [
        'experience' => 174,
        'level' => 3],
    '23' => [
        'experience' => 83,
        'level' => 2],
    '24' => [
        'experience' => 1,
        'level' => 1],
];

function experience($L)
{
    $a = 0;
    for ($x = 1; $x < $L; $x++) {
        $a += floor($x + 300 * pow(2, ($x / 7)));
    }
    return floor($a / 4);
}
function level($experience)
{
    $returned = 0;
    $level = 0;
    while ($returned <= $experience) {
        $level++;
        $returned = experience($level);
    }
    return $level - 1;
}

function calcNextLevel($arr, $current_experience)
{

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if ((int) experience($value["level"]) <= $current_experience) {
            $diff_experience_till_next_level = $arr[(int) $key - 1]["experience"] - $current_experience;
            // you need a simple equation here to calculate the difference or percentage to next level or based on all levels
            $percentage = 100 * (abs($arr[(int) $key - 1]["experience"] - $arr[(int) $key]["experience"]) / 10000);
            echo "YAAAY!  " . $percentage . "% left to go to next level!";
            break;
        }

    }
}

calcNextLevel($arr, 4000);
```

#### Ouput

For an input of 4,000 as experience, it would return:

```
YAAAY!  4.97% left to go to next level!
```